# Java: Downloading .Zip files from an FTP and extracting the contents without saving the files on local system

Tags: java, hadoop, ftp, zip

I have a requirement in which I need to download certain .Zip files from an FTP server, and push the contents of the archive(contents are some XML files) to **HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System)**. Hence as of now, I'm using **acpache FTPClient** to connect to the FTP server and downloading the files to my local machine first. Later unzipping the same and giving out the folder path to a method which will iterate the local folder and push the files to HDFS. For easy understanding, I'm also attaching some code snippets below.

```
 //Gives me an active FTPClient
    FTPClient ftpCilent = getActiveFTPConnection();
    ftpCilent.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteDirectory);

    FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpCilent.listFiles();
    if(ftpFiles.length <= 0){
    logger.info("Unable to find any files in given location!!");
    return;
    }
    //Iterate files
    for(FTPFile eachFTPFile : ftpFiles){
        String ftpFileName = eachFTPFile.getName();

        //Skips files if not .zip files
        if(!ftpFileName.endsWith(".zip")){
           continue;
        }

    System.out.println("Reading File -->" + ftpFileName);
    /*
     * location is the path on local system given by user
     * usually loaded by a property file.
     *
     * Create a archiveLocation where archived files are
     * downloaded from FTP.
     */
    String archiveFileLocation = location + File.separator + ftpFileName;
    String localDirName = ftpFileName.replaceAll(".zip", "");
    /*
     * localDirLocation is the location where a folder is created
     * by the name of the archive in the FTP and the files are copied to
     * respective folders.
     *
     */
    String localDirLocation = location + File.separator + localDirName;
    File localDir = new File(localDirLocation);
    localDir.mkdir();

    File archiveFile = new File(archiveFileLocation);

    FileOutputStream archiveFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(archiveFile);

    ftpCilent.retrieveFile(ftpFileName, archiveFileOutputStream);
    archiveFileOutputStream.close();

    //Delete the archive file after coping it's contents
    FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit(archiveFile);

    //Read the archive file from archiveFileLocation.       
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(archiveFileLocation);
    Enumeration entries = zip.entries();

    while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)entries.nextElement();

    if(entry.isDirectory()){
        logger.info("Extracting directory " + entry.getName());
        (new File(entry.getName())).mkdir();
        continue;
    }

    logger.info("Extracting File: " + entry.getName());
    IOUtils.copy(zip.getInputStream(entry), new FileOutputStream(
    localDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + entry.getName()));
    }

    zip.close();
   /*
    * Iterates the folder location provided and load the files to HDFS
    */    
    loadFilesToHDFS(localDirLocation);
    }
    disconnectFTP();
```

Now, the problem with this approach is, the app is taking lot of time to download files to local path, unzip it and then load them to HDFS. Is there a better way in which I can extract the contents of Zip from FTP **on the fly** and give a stream of contents directly to the method `loadFilesToHDFS()` rather than path to local system?

Comment: `ZipInputStream`? Also, this is 2016, so avoid using `File`... Use `Files` and `Path` instead

Comment: Hey @fge, I could have used `ZipInputStream`, but it takes `InputStream` as an input where as from `FTPClient` writes to an `OutputStream`. So I'm facing a time lag in writing to `FileOutputStream` and reading from the same as an `InputStream`. Any suggestions on this scenario?

Comment: Look at the documentation of `FTPClient`... There _is_ a method for what you want: it's called `.retrieveFileStream()`.

Comment: Hey @fge Thanks a lot for your inputs. That worked well.!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a zip stream.
see here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html

specifically see code sample 1 there.